# Implement Socket class in java for special purpose

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm pretty new to Java programming and I don't have permission to use java built-in libraries, specifically **Socket** and **ServerSocket**. I should implement a server-client program that whenever client connects to the server, server gets its name and give them some tasks.

My question is how to implement the Socket and ServerSocket for this purpose. I have searched over internet and the results was disappointing for me. 
I would be Thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: If you don't have permissions to use the built in library then you wont be able to do it because eventually everything will end up using those libraries even 3rd party libraries. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @locus2k I just have permission to use  DataInput/OutputStream class. Socket and ServerSocket is forbidden for university assignment of network course. :(

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, if its a network course why would they forbid you to use the actual class to communicate?

Comment: @locus2k maybe to understand the basic things of network. I don't know this assignment sounds weird to me :(

Comment: Guess you can start with the socket source code: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/net/Socket.java

Comment: I'm 99.9% certain you have misunderstood your assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to establish a TCP connection without Java's `Socket` (or `AsynchronousSocketChannel`) or accept TCP connections without Java's `ServerSocket` (or `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel`) I would say that you cannot do it, ***in Java***.

If you read the code of these classes, you will find many **native** method calls, meaning native OS-specific code is being used.

So you *could* write some C code to implement your own version of a TCP connection and use it in your Java code using **JNI**.

Is that what this assignment is supposed to make you learn ?